# how do i read header info metadata from office documents if data is in bytes format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

xml documents are in zip container and the data is in bytes form, I want to confirm from header or signature or magic number about file type.

```
import binascii

from_folder='G:/WORK JOB/Test.docx'
with open (from_folder, "rb") as myfile:
    header =myfile.read(24)
    header = str(binascii.hexlify(header))[2:-1]
    print(header)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: The thing is my code is incomplete. I don't know how to verify file type from byte data.